# Images not loading when selected

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

I have a `JSplitPane` which ideally should work like this-

A `JList` on the left should have names that correspond to a picture displayed in a `JLabel` on the right.

The pictures can be found in an images folder located in the project's root directory.

For whatever reason, selecting an item in the `JList` on the left bears no effect on the `JLabel` on the right.

```
public class TextureChooser {

static Main main;

JSplitPane splitPane;
JList textureList;
JLabel texturePic;
String[] textures = {"grass", "stone", "water"};
ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("/Users/seanweber/Desktop/Textures/stone.jpg");

public TextureChooser(){
    textureList = new JList(textures);
    texturePic = new JLabel(ic);
    splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, textureList, texturePic);
}

//Listens to the list
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    JList list = (JList)e.getSource();
    updateLabel(textures[list.getSelectedIndex()]);
}

//Renders the selected image
protected void updateLabel (String name) {
    ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/" + name + ".png");
    texturePic.setIcon(icon);
    if  (icon != null) {
        texturePic.setText(null);
    } else {
        texturePic.setText("Image not found");
    }
}

/** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
   URL imgPath = main.getClass().getResource(path);
    if (imgPath != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgPath);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The path to the images directory looks like this.

```
- ProjectRoot
  - images
    - stone
    - grass
    - water
```

My initial assumption is that I'm retrieving the images incorrectly...

Much of the code was taken directly from an example on Oracle's site [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/SplitPaneDemoProject/src/components/SplitPaneDemo.java).

Comment: Does it ever print `Couldn't find file: ...`?  The likely cause is, the images are not within the context of the application's class-path and therefore can't be loaded using `Class#getResource`.  Have you tried using `new ImageIcon(path);` instead?

Comment: The JLabel on the right is completely blank at all times. I will attempt to implement your suggestion although if you can't tell my IO skills are pretty weak. :P

Comment: If the image can't be loaded, this `System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);` will display an error message to console

Comment: I changed the image icon in the updateLabel() method to an external path that I know for a fact it can reach and still got no reaction at all from the JLabel. I also have never gotten the err under any circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added a `ListSelectionListener` to the `textureList`...

```
textureList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        JList list = (JList) e.getSource();
        updateLabel(textures[list.getSelectedIndex()]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow... Now I'm only getting an NPE on this line `ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/" + name + ".png");`

Comment: That lines not likely to cause a NPE for any reasons,  In fact, the only point I can see you getting a NPE is here `URL imgPath = main.getClass().getResource(path);`, because `main` is `null`.  You probably should be using `TextureChooser.class.getResource(path);`, but this may require you to prefix your path with `/` as well

Comment: The only problem with that is that I now get the error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object`

Comment: `TextureChooser.class` not `TextureChooser.getClass()`

Comment: Yup, that did the trick. I now get the error `"Couldn't find file: " + path` which is certainly a step in the right direction.

Comment: Now, either the files aren't with the `class-path` context of your application or you need to try using `"/images/" + name + ".png"` and `"images/" + name + ".png"`.  `Class#getResource` will only load resources that it can find within the class path. You need to be sure that the images are either stored within your application context (within the Jar or at the root directory where your classes are stored) or use a relative path context instead

Comment: I solved the problem by switching to the Navigator view in Eclipse, and after finding that the images folder was on the same level as the bin folder, I moved the images folder into the bin. Now I just have to play with the swing positioning and sizing of my split pane. Thank you for your time and help! I am now one step closer to completing my tile map editor.